# Can cos(a) ever equal 0 in floating point

Tags: floating-point, trigonometry

Given that PI/2 can never be represented precisely in floating point, is it safe to assume that cos(a) can never return exact zero?

If this is the case, then the following pseudo-code will never enter the block (and it could be safely removed):

```
...
y = h/cos(a);
if (!isfinite(a))
{
  // handle infinite y
}
```

Comment: Sometimes the system might force it zero when `a` is aprox. equal to `pi/2`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Zero is one of several values that can be represented exactly.  Many systems have a lookup table for common values of sin and cos, so it's not inconceivable that exactly zero could be returned.

But you are safer using a delta compare, before performing the division:

```
if (Abs(cos(a)) < 0.0000001)
{

}
```

Comment: One of "several"?  I don't think I would use the term "several" for (2^64 - 2^53).

Comment: Every finite floating-point value can be represented exactly in floating-point (shocking, I know).  Not only 1/2, 1/4, but also 0.333333333333333314829616256247390992939472198486328125 and 3.141592653589790007373494518105871975421905517578125.

Comment: Every finite **floating-point** value can be represented exactly.  1/3 is not a floating-point value, but quintillions of numbers are.

Comment: you seem to be getting confused. I stated "Zero is one of several values that can be represented exactly". I didn't add "finite floating-point value ".

Comment: I assure you, I am not confused.  There are literally quintillions of numbers ("values") that can be represented exactly in floating-point.  By my reasoning, that's rather more than "several".

Comment: yes, stephen. I know that. Several is still quintillions. Did you have anything to add to the answers here?

Answer (score 7):

Other than zero, the double precision value that comes closest to an exact multiple of π/2 is 6381956970095103 * 2^797, which is equal to:

```
(an odd integer) * π/2 + 2.983942503748063...e−19
```

Thus, for all double-precision values x, we have the bound:

```
|cos(x)| >= cos(2.983942503748063...e−19)
```

Note that this is a bound on the mathematically exact value, not on the value returned by the library function `cos`.  On a platform with a good-quality math library, this bound is sufficiently good that we can say that `cos(x)` is not zero for any double-precision `x`.  In fact, it turns out that this is not unique to double; this property holds for all IEEE-754 basic types, if `cos` is faithfully rounded.

However, that's not to say that this could never occur on a platform that had a spectacularly poor implementation of trigonometric argument reduction.

Even more importantly, it's critical to note that in your example `y` can be infinite *without* `cos(a)` being zero:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    double a = 0x1.6ac5b262ca1ffp+849;
    double h = 0x1.0p1022;
    printf("cos(a) = %g\n", cos(a));
    printf("h/cos(a) = %g\n", h/cos(a));
    return 0;
}
```

compile and run:

```
scanon$ clang example.c && ./a.out
cos(a) = -4.68717e-19
h/cos(a) = -inf
```

Comment: I would have liked to answer exactly this, and beside it gives clues why a tolerance like 0.0000001 sounds completely arbitrary, it would even not prevent an overflow. The overflow protection should be something like if(abs(cos(x)) < 1) ;)

Answer (score 0):

no, this cannot be guaranteed, because `cos` is itself computed with an error, so its value can be an exact zero pretty easily.